# I need to compare collection using cursors in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare

    cursor c1 is
    select last_name ls  from empc;

    type x is table of employees.last_name%type;
    x1 x := x();
    cnt integer :=0;

begin

    for z in c1 loop

        cnt := cnt +1;
        x1.extend;
        x1(cnt) := z.ls;

        if x1(cnt) = 'NULL' then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---');
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line(cnt || ' '|| x1(cnt));

    end loop;

end;
```

In this code I need to replace the null values with some value in this case (------). But i am not able to find an solution .

Comment: Hard to understand what you're trying to do: in `empc` tbale, do you have null values or strings with 'NULL'? and are you trying to initialize `x1(cnt)` with the new value (other than `null`)? If you have null values, why not use `NVL` function in the cursor's query? and why are you looping and not using `bulk collect`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want `X1` to have different values than nulls.

You can use NVL function in your query (cursor) like this:

```
cursor c1 is
select nvl(last_name, '----') ls  from empc;
```

But if it's all you're trying to do then you can make the whole thing even simpler:

```
declare

    type x is table of employees.last_name%type;
    x1 x := x();

begin

    select nvl(last_name, '---') ls bulk collect into x1 from empc;

    -- This is just for printing the results
    for cnt in x1.first .. x1.last loop

        dbms_output.put_line(cnt || ' '|| x1(cnt));

    end loop;

end;
```